# Speeding up getting data MYSQL (inplanting)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a learning programmer and I'm trying to learn PHP.
Now the point is that I use alot of db connections in my new project. This are alot of different DB's an require different connection.

Does anybody a way where I can create a function what makes me use my code like this? `Getdata($User, $beerbrand, $sales);` and use these variables in my code? I use the same way to get the data out of the database everytime. But it's alot of code, where I think it should be possible to make that a little easier.

The way I use now:

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
 $stuff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM beers ORDER BY ID");
    while($frontstuff = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
        $us = $frontstuff['Beer'];
    }
```

If you think this is a stupid question, please be gentle and explain it to me in a easy way.

Best regards

Comment: You can use Oops. Create class and functions.And  call The function as per your requirement.

Comment: Can you prove a tutorial link with that, since I'm new I keep hitting the wrong links at google, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @EvertArends google.com please. You don't need to connect to the database everytime. Please store the connection info in a single file and refer it everytime you needed. Or Even better use OOPS

Comment: Mysqli or pdo might be in your near future too

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, and @ling.s I did google, but nothing sattified my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    class Database {

            private $connection;    //Database Connection Link
            private $userName;      //Database server User Name
            private $password;      //Database server Password
            private $database;      //Database Name
            private $hostname;      //Name of database server

            public function __construct() {
                $this->hostname=your servername
                $this->userName=yourusername
                $this->password=yourpasswrod
                $this->database=your bb name
                try {
                    $this->connectlink = mysql_connect($this->hostname,$this->userName,$this->password);
                    if(!($this->connectlink)) {
                        throw new Exception("Error Connecting to the Database".mysql_error(),"101");
                    }
                    if(!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connectlink)) {
                        throw new Exception("Error Connecting to the Database1".mysql_error(),"101");
                    }
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    //print_r($dbConfig);
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }

            }

            public function __destruct() {
                @mysql_close($this->connectlink);
            }
}
```

you can crete a database file like this for specifying connnection
and you can use this file in processing your query in another pages.Eg

```
<?php
include_once("database.php");

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function getstuf($parameter){
        $stuff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM beers ORDER BY ID");
    while($frontstuff = mysql_fetch_array($stuff)){
        $us = $frontstuff['Beer'];
    }
return stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I don't get why someone downvoted this. A little question: Is this safe for use? I mean not vuln to SQL injection etc? If it's not, than this is exactly what I need!

Comment: @ Vishal not until I know if this is safe for use (SQL Injection etc.). I don't wan't others to get dangerous code.